# Running jobs in background in Unix

Tags: unix

We run an interactive perl script which takes a set of inputs(an input which is time till which the script should run) from the terminal and runs till the completion. The job runs in the foreground. I have made the job to run in the background by hitting `CTRL-Z` followed by `bg %-` command.
Once the current job runs in the background, if I run the same perl script with a different set of inputs and try to put it into the background the first job is getting terminated when I hit `CTRL-Z` as follows.

^Z[1]   Terminated              scriptname

[2]+  Stopped                 scriptname

Please point out if I am making any mistake

Answer (score 0):

When you press ^Z the running script is stopped and after bg it will continue (in the background).
You get the feedback of the bg job when you do something on the commandline.
With `[1] Terminated scriptname` you see that the first script is finished. With `[2]+ Stopped scriptname` you see the second job is paused and waiting for a bg/fg command.
Using ^Z + bg is about the same as appending `&` to your command (for not interactive programs). You can try things with

```
sleep 1 &
# now wait few seconds
ps
# you will see the terminated script

sleep 6 &
sleep 3; ps
sleep 4; ps

# and now repeat these cases with ^Z / bg instead of &
```

Answer (score 0):

try nohup

```
nohup nice <your_script followed by parameters(separated by space)> &
```

It will give you process_id. Hit Ctrl+C to exit the command and verify by ps -ef that it is still running. I remember running multiple instance of same script with different parameter like this.